# A word or phrase for a fake doctors or healers

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I am looking for a word to describe people that proclaim that they possess healing powers or know remedies to cure incurable conditions or even to poses spiritual powers. A general term would be a charlatan but I want something specific. Something like the word alchemist compared to a chemist. Few words, I can think of are fake shaman, fake healers, plastic shaman, voodoo priest.

Comment: *Quack*, *fraud*, *charlatan*, *snake-oil salesman*.

Comment: Bogus Doctor, Bogus healer

Comment: The term ***[mountebank](http://thefreedictionary.com/mountebank)*** primarily signifies a hawker of quack medicines. It is a bit old-fashioned sounding, though.

Comment: How about Scientologist, as they as a group have had a history of claiming to be able to cure cancer, among other things :P

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you are talking medicine (including pseudo-scientific medicine) then you want either quack or snake-oil salesman.

[Quack](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/quack) (MW, noun definitions 1 & 2)

> charlatan
>
> a pretender to medical skill

[Snake-oil](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/snake-oil) (MW)

> any of various substances or mixtures sold (as by a traveling medicine show) as medicine usually without regard to their medical worth or properties

[Snake-oil salesman](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/snake-oil-salesman) (Cambridge)

> someone who deceives people in order to get money from them

Comment: As a Brit, I wouldn't necessarily associate "Snake-oil salesman" with medicine/healing.  That seems to be borne out by the different definitions in MW & Cambridge dictionaries. "Quack" would be my preferred choice.

Comment: I agree with TrevorD: it should be Quack, and not Snake-oil salesman. A snake-oil salesman is primarily a salesman, not a doctor. Doctors (and quacks) do a lot more than just prescribe medicine.

Answer (score 1):

"Quack" is the most common term I know of. Occasionally, it can be used as a derogatory term for any medical doctor

If you want something a bit more verbose/proper, use the original term "Quacksalver"

From Wiktionary:

> c 1570, from Dutch kwakzalver ‎(“hawker of salve”), from Middle Dutch quacken ‎(“to brag, boast; to croak”)

i.e. Someone who boasts about the potency of their remedies, but is in fact a fraud.